# Rails "Data too long for column" error after truncation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, controller, truncate

I have an app that creates text excerpts from body text entered into the model and it seems to work fine except, for some reason, when i try to enter one particular string into the body text.

in my blog_post model I have

```
t.string   "excerpt",            limit: 114
```

in my controller i am creating the excerpt string by doing this:

```
def create
  @blogpost = Blogpost.new(blogpost_params)
  @excerpt = @blogpost.body
  @blogpost.excerpt = truncate(@excerpt, :length => 114)
  respond_to do |format|
   if @blogpost.save
    etc,etc,
end
```

This seems to work fine most of the time but i entered the following text as a test

```
 You know how they used to say It's #Sinatra's world, the rest of us are just living in it. - well, it's as true today as it was then. Check out Frank. When he gets out of a #chopper, dressed in a perfect lounge suit, #cocktail in hand, his #hat stays perfectly tilted. When I get out of a #chopper (and I'm not talking about once or twice but every single time I ever get out of a chopper) the spinning blades blow my hat all over the place. #Milliners should think about that and you should too the next time you're out hat shopping.
```

(sorry it's a bit long) I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in MoansController#create
Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'excerpt' at row 1....
```

It looks like the truncate isn't working for some reason.. Is it something to do with this text or have i missed something else?

Comment: How this column is defined in MySQL? What's the maximum length there?

Comment: Which version of Rails do you use?

Comment: It's rails 4 and the migration used to add the column was add_column(:blogposts, "excerpt", :string, :limit=>114)

Comment: try to truncate to 111 characters

Comment: @IvanDenisov That shouldnt be a problem the `:limit => 114` does include the `...` to the limitation count.

Comment: Add `logger.info "TRUNCATED BODY: #{@blogpost.excerpt} COUNT: #{@blogpost.excerpt.length}"` to your controller before `save` so you can see if the trunction works right or not. This will be writen to the environment logfile by default.

Comment: oh @davidb the truncated text is 126 characters    `TRUNCATED BODY:  You know how they used to say It&#39;s #Sinatra&#39;s world, the rest of us are just living in it. - well, it&#39;s as tru... COUNT: 126` It looks like the non ASCII character codes are causing the problem.. Any idea how i would address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove the database restriction and handle this by using a setter that truncates to the wanted length by default. In you model add `excerpt_setter` to the `attr_accessible` list. And then define it like this

```
def excerpt_setter=(str)
  self.excerpt = truncate(str, :length => 114)
end

def excerpt_setter
  self.excerpt
end
```

And then in the controller

```
def create
  @blogpost = Blogpost.new(blogpost_params)
  @blogpost.excerpt_setter = truncate(@excerpt.body, :length => 114)
  respond_to do |format|
   if @blogpost.save
    etc,etc,
end
```

Another thing: You can also define a `excerpt` method in your model and drop the field if there isnt any good reason to store a part of the body in another field.

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper  # this is needed to make the truncate method avaiable in model

...
...
...

def excerpt
  truncate(self.body, :length => 114)
end
```

If you dont need the data stored in the database for performence reasons this whould be my prefered solution.

Comment: which of the solutions?

Comment: I went for the second option of defining the excerpt in the model.. I think i was over complicating things before